# Excel VBA - Returning Positions of all Sub-Strings within a String from the Clipboard

Tags: regex, vba, excel

I'm trying to find all the positions of the unique keys (followed by two Tab keystrokes) in a string in taken from clipboard, positions with which I then hope to use to insert carriage returns, and then have everything put back into the clipboard again.

First things first; getting the position part to work!

Here is a shortened example of the string:

```
Initial Approval in First Market or Non-Submitted Closure       090052fb842ef82f        090052fb842f3659        090052fb842ef82e
```

Here is the non-functional code I have put together so far from researching the problem:

```
Sub oldRecords()

Dim clipboard As MSForms.DataObject
Dim strContents As String

Set clipboard = New MSForms.DataObject
clipboard.GetFromClipboard
strContents = clipboard.GetText

Set objRegEx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
objRegEx.Pattern = "(090052fb)[0-9A-Za-z]{8}\t\t"
objRegEx.Global = True
objRegEx.IgnoreCase = True
objRegEx.MultiLine = True

Start = 1
Do
  pos = InStr(Start, strContents, objRegEx.Execute(strContents), vbBinaryCompare)
  If pos > 0 Then
    Start = pos + Len(objRegEx.Pattern)
    WScript.Echo pos
    WScript.Echo Mid(strContents, pos, Len(objRegEx.Pattern))
  End If
Loop While pos > 0

End Sub
```

Right now I am getting a Run-time error '450': Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment, and I believe the culprit is:

```
objRegEx.Execute(strContents)
```

I'm not sure where to go from here, so any help would be fantastic! :)

Edit 1:
Firstly thank you for the interest in my issue!

BrackNicku has provided a simple solution for a problem I evidently thought more complex than it needed to be! Here is the code I finally went with, adding in a few extra bits that I needed on top of the core issue:

```
Sub oldRecords2()
    Dim clipboard As MSForms.DataObject
    Dim strContents As String
    Dim start As Long, pos As Long

    Set clipboard = New MSForms.DataObject
    clipboard.GetFromClipboard
    strContents = clipboard.GetText
    Dim objRegEx
    Set objRegEx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    objRegEx.Pattern = "(090052fb[0-9A-Za-z]{8})\t\t"
    objRegEx.Global = True
    objRegEx.IgnoreCase = True
    objRegEx.MultiLine = True

    X1 = 10                                                                     ' Line Feed Character
    X2 = 13                                                                     ' Carriage Return Character
    X3 = "Archive Custodain Group"
    X4 = "Archive Custodain Group" & Chr(X2)
    '======================================================================================================

    strContents = Replace(strContents, Chr(X1), "")                             ' REMOVES LINE FEEDS
    strContents = Replace(strContents, X3, X4)                                  ' ADDS CR AFTER TITLE ROW

    strContents = objRegEx.Replace(strContents, "$1" & vbNewLine)
    '======================================================================================================

    clipboard.SetText strContents                                               'PUT BACK INTO CLIPBOARD
    clipboard.PutInClipboard
End Sub
```

Comment: Could you please add the expected result? Note that `pos + Len(objRegEx.Pattern)` is wrong, as you add the length of the pattern, and not the match. Probably you need to find the match itself and get its index.

Comment: I got `59`, `77` and `95`, is that expected? Tested against `strContents = "Initial Approval in First Market or Non-Submitted Closure" & vbTab & vbTab & "090052fb842ef82f" & vbTab & vbTab & "090052fb842f3659" & vbTab & vbTab & "090052fb842ef82e" & vbTab & vbTab`

Comment: If I add the match output, I also get `090052fb842ef82f`, `090052fb842f3659`, `090052fb842ef82e`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm trying to find all the positions of the unique keys (followed by
>   two Tab keystrokes) in a string in taken from clipboard, positions
>   with which I then hope to use to insert carriage returns, and then
>   have everything put back into the clipboard again.

If you want to insert new lines before each key, then instead of locating the keys and inserting new lines, you could try `RegExp.Replace`

```
strContents = objRegEx.Replace(strContents, vbNewLine & "$1")
```

You have to modify the pattern to include whole key in the group:

```
objRegEx.Pattern = "(090052fb[0-9A-Za-z]{8})\t\t"
```

Result:

> Initial Approval in First Market or Non-Submitted Closure
>   090052fb842ef82f
>   090052fb842f3659
>   090052fb842ef82e

Full code (with new line after pattern):

```
Sub oldRecords()
    Dim clipboard As MSForms.DataObject
    Dim strContents As String

    Set clipboard = New MSForms.DataObject
    clipboard.GetFromClipboard
    strContents = clipboard.GetText
    Dim objRegEx
    Set objRegEx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    objRegEx.Pattern = "(090052fb[0-9A-Za-z]{8})\t\t"
    objRegEx.Global = True
    objRegEx.IgnoreCase = True
    objRegEx.MultiLine = True

    strContents = objRegEx.Replace(strContents,"$1" & vbNewLine)
    'Put back to clipboard
    clipboard.SetText strContents
    clipboard.PutInClipboard
End Sub
```

Comment: This sounds close to perfect, but I couldn't get it to work and I need the returns after the pattern specifically. Could you post all the code you used to make this work in an edit?

Comment: @HotSauceCoconuts I've added the code (almost the same as yours). If you want to save the tabs - include them in brackets in pattern. If you want only CR, use `vbCr` instead of `vbNewLine`

Comment: haha you really saved my bacon dude :D Our office will be forever indebted to you

Answer (score 2):

When you run `objRegEx.Execute(strContents)`, it returns a match collection. Then, you are not even using the results as `Len(objRegEx.Pattern)` returns the length of the *pattern* and not the *match*.

It seems you just want to obtain the matches and their indices in the string. Remove all starting from `Start = 1` and ending with `Loop While pos > 0` and use

```
Dim ms As Object, m As Object
'...
objRegEx.Pattern = "(090052fb[0-9A-Za-z]{8})\t\t"
'...
Set ms = objRegEx.Execute(strContents)
For Each m In ms
    WScript.Echo m.FirstIndex
    WScript.Echo m.SubMatches(0)
Next
```

Tested with

```
strContents = "Initial Approval in First Market or Non-Submitted Closure" & vbTab & vbTab & "090052fb842ef82f" & vbTab & vbTab & "090052fb842f3659" & vbTab & vbTab & "090052fb842ef82e" & vbTab & vbTab
```

Result:

```
 59 
090052fb842ef82f
 77 
090052fb842f3659
 95 
090052fb842ef82e
```

Note I moved the capturing group around all but tab pattern, `(090052fb[0-9A-Za-z]{8})\t\t`, feel free to adjust as per your needs.

Comment: If there is a problem accessing Group 1 value, try `m.SubMatches.Item(0)`

Answer (score 0):

Using your string example I came into this:

```
Sub findKeyPositions()

    Dim str As String
    Dim splitStr() As String
    Dim searchStr As String

    str = "Initial Approval in First Market or Non-Submitted Closure       090052fb842ef82f        090052fb842f3659        090052fb842ef82e        "
    splitStr() = Split(Replace(str, "090052fb", ""), "       ") 'in your example i did it with 7 spaces and not vbtab

    For i = LBound(splitStr) To UBound(splitStr)
        searchStr = Trim(splitStr(i))
        Debug.Print (InStr(1, str, searchStr, vbTextCompare))
    Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your post correctly you want to replace the Tabs with CR
If so, then there's no need to find the positions, you could just replace.

```
Sub replaceTab()

Dim clipboard As MSForms.DataObject

Set clipboard = New MSForms.DataObject
clipboard.GetFromClipboard
clipboard.SetText Replace(clipboard.GetText, vbTab, vbCrLf)
clipboard.PutInClipboard

End Sub
```